# Restoring Notes on macOS High Sierra

Tags: macos, high-sierra, notes.app, data-recovery

I would like to view some old notes that were deleted.  I read online that the notes are stored through:

1. ~/Library/Group Containers/group.com.apple.notes: NoteStore.sqlite files.

OR

2. ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Notes/Data/Library/Notes/ NotesV7.storedata files.

Do these contain old notes or just the current notes?  Thanks!

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). As for your question, I've added some tags (including one for the Notes app), so if this isn't correct you'll need to remove that tag and edit your question to clarify what type of notes were deleted. Also, it'd be good if you could clarify whether you have a backup (Time Machine, etc) and what settings you have relating to iCloud? These details will help clarify your possible options.

Comment: Thank you.  I'm not sure if time machine is activated because when I go to ~/Library/Group Containers/group.com.apple.notes and activate time machine I see a stack of finder windows but clicking the side buttons to scroll through history does not work.  I did not set up iCloud.

Comment: The directories I mentioned are supposed to store the notes files but I don't know if they store a history of notes or just the current notes.